# Conversion to String

Tags: java

In the code I want the result of the operation to be displayed in a textarea but, as the variables in some cases reach nine zeros the answer is shown as "10E9" and I tried to solve how you can see them in the code but it didn't work, I would like you to help me with this`your text

```
 private void CalcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       String _A = JTbanda1.getText();
       String _B = JTbanda2.getText();
       String _C = JTbanda3.getText();
       String _D=JTbanda4.getText();
       double A = Double.parseDouble(_A);
       double B = Double.parseDouble(_B);
       double C = Double.parseDouble(_C);
       double resistencia = (A + B) * C;
       String _resul = Double.toString(resistencia);
resul.setText("La resistencia segun los colores es:\n" + _resul+
        "\n El valor de la banda1 es: "+_A+
        "\n El valor de la banda2 es: "+_B+
        "\n El valor de la banda3 es: "+_C+
        "\n La tolerancias es de: "+_D
);

    }
```

Comment: Always search for your answer before posting. It's unlikely you're the first to ever ask the question.